# Find longest common substring of array of Strings

Tags: ios, algorithm, swift3, lcs, longest-substring

In my Swift 3.0 app, I want to determine the best name for something by finding the longest common substring of 6 to 12 strings.

**Example strings:**

```
ON/OFF office lights
DIM office lights
VALUE office lights
FB office lights
FB VALUE office lights
```

**Desired output:**

```
office lights
```

I've come across multiple StackOverflow answers for the longest subsequence but haven't been able to adapt any of them to my needs..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I will be the obvious guy here and forward you to Wikipedia. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) has a very good pseudocode which you can adapt to Swift.

Comment: @the4kman I spent half an hour trying, but my knowledge about arrays in Swift is too limited to accomplish this..

Comment: I updated my answer , sorry for 1hr delay @BramRoelandts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I converted **Java** & **C++** code into **Swift 3** , collected from **GeeksForGeeks** [Longest Common Subsequence](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-longest-common-subsequence/) & [Longest Common Substring](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring/).

It works !

```
class LongestCommon
{
    // Returns length of LCS for X[0..m-1], Y[0..n-1]
    private static func lcSubsequence(_ X : String  , _ Y : String  ) -> String
    {
        let m = X.characters.count
        let n = Y.characters.count

        var L = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: n + 1 ) , count: m + 1)
        // Following steps build L[m+1][n+1] in bottom up fashion. Note
        // that L[i][j] contains length of LCS of X[0..i-1] and Y[0..j-1]
        for i in stride(from: 0, through: m, by: 1)
        {
            for j in stride(from: 0, through: n, by: 1)
            {
                if i == 0 || j == 0
                {
                    L[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else if X[X.index( X.startIndex , offsetBy: (i - 1) )] == Y[Y.index( Y.startIndex , offsetBy: (j - 1) )]
                {
                    L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1] + 1
                }
                else
                {
                   L[i][j] = max(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1])
                }
            }

        }

        // Following code is used to print LCS
        var index = L[m][n]
        // Create a character array to store the lcs string
        var lcs = ""
        // Start from the right-most-bottom-most corner and
        // one by one store characters in lcs[]
        var i = m
        var j = n

        while (i > 0 && j > 0)
        {
            // If current character in X[] and Y are same, then
            // current character is part of LCS
            if X[X.index( X.startIndex , offsetBy: (i - 1) )] == Y[Y.index( Y.startIndex , offsetBy: (j - 1) )]
            {
                lcs.append(X[X.index( X.startIndex , offsetBy: (i - 1) )])
                i-=1
                j-=1
                index-=1
            }
            // If not same, then find the larger of two and
            // go in the direction of larger value
            else if (L[i-1][j] > L[i][j-1])
            {
                i-=1
            }
            else
            {
                j-=1
            }
        }

        // return the lcs
        return String(lcs.characters.reversed())
    }

    // Returns length of LCS for X[0..m-1], Y[0..n-1]
    private static func lcSubstring(_ X : String  , _ Y : String  ) -> String
    {
        let m = X.characters.count
        let n = Y.characters.count

        var L = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: n + 1 ) , count: m + 1)
        var result : (length : Int, iEnd : Int, jEnd : Int) = (0,0,0)
        // Following steps build L[m+1][n+1] in bottom up fashion. Note
        // that L[i][j] contains length of LCS of X[0..i-1] and Y[0..j-1]
        for i in stride(from: 0, through: m, by: 1)
        {
            for j in stride(from: 0, through: n, by: 1)
            {
                if i == 0 || j == 0
                {
                    L[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else if X[X.index( X.startIndex , offsetBy: (i - 1) )] == Y[Y.index( Y.startIndex , offsetBy: (j - 1) )]
                {
                    L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1] + 1

                    if result.0 < L[i][j]
                    {
                        result.length = L[i][j]
                        result.iEnd = i
                        result.jEnd = j
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    L[i][j] = 0 //max(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1])
                }
            }

        }

        // Following code is used to print LCS


        let lcs = X.substring(with: X.index(X.startIndex, offsetBy: result.iEnd-result.length)..<X.index(X.startIndex, offsetBy: result.iEnd))

        // return the lcs
        return lcs
    }

    // driver program

    class func subsequenceOf(_ strings : [String] ) -> String
    {
        var answer = strings[0] // For on string answer is itself

        for i in stride(from: 1, to: strings.count, by: 1)
        {
            answer = lcSubsequence(answer,strings[i])
        }
        return answer
    }

    class func substringOf(_ strings : [String] ) -> String
    {
        var answer = strings[0] // For on string answer is itself

        for i in stride(from: 1, to: strings.count, by: 1)
        {
            answer = lcSubstring(answer,strings[i])
        }
        return answer
    }



}
```

**Usage :**

```
let strings = ["ON/OFF office lights",
                       "DIM office lights",
                       "VALUE office lights",
                       "FB office lights",
                       "FB VALUE office lights"]
print(LongestCommon.subsequenceOf(strings))
print(LongestCommon.substringOf(strings))
```

Comment: I tested this code some more and this is actually the longest common subsequence of an array of strings, not the longest common **substring**. When passing ["ON/OFF office lights", "FB office lights"], the output will be "F office lights". Any idea how I could tweak your code for that purpose?

Comment: @BramRoelandts Check My answer Now !

Comment: I tried your new answer and I actually still get the same results. When passing an array of strings with five items, it returns "office lights" as desired, but when passing only two elements (["ON/OFF office lights", "FB office lights"]), it returns "F office lights" for both substring and subsequence. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually you are looking for Longest Common Sub Words not Substring nor Subsequence ,  By Algorithm my code is correct,  I believe ! Substring and Subsequence finding basically works of Characters not words generally. btw. .  It is still applicable and easier.

Comment: Well, not entirely - I generally don't care about words or characters. When you look carefully, if "F office lights" is the longest common substring between ["ON/OFF office lights", "FB office lights"], your algorithm dropped the 'B' in the second string. All characters in the common substring have to immediately follow each other, there can't be dropped ones..

Comment: Oh,I see, as I am away from my mac,  I will update my code by tommorow 10:30 a.m. GMT+6

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting in the effort of helping me with this! Curious to see if you'll manage it, as I sure as hell wouldn't know how..